# "echo" is displayed in a Laravel Componet

Tags: laravel

I am looking for a way to pass variables of PHP from parent blade to a component.

I made a component like this

hooo.blade.php

```
<form method ="GET" action={{ route('update')}}>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ $value }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>
            <button type = "submit" class ="button">SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I called it

```
@include('hooo', [
    'name' => 'name',
    'value' => '{{$value}}'
])
```

but then created HTML is

```
<input id="name" type="text" class="form-control"
    name="name" value="&lt;?php echo e($value); ?&gt;"
    required autocomplete="name" autofocus>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like that is the PHP created from it. If that's the case, it'll be correctly evaluated once served.

Comment: Try `'value' => $value`

Answer (score 0):

Hello guy you forgot brackets " ( ) "

```
<?php echo ($value) ?>
```